# How does unicode-range work with ligatures?

Tags: css, font-face, ligature, unicode-range

When using `unicode-range` in a `@font-face` block, how are ligatures included?

If a ligature contains a mixture of glyphs both inside and outside the range(s) provided by `unicode-range`, is that font included in the ligature, or will the browser try to find a more appropriate font?

Alternatively, does it require that all of the ligature's glyphs are included in the font for it to render the ligature?

Is any of this in the specification? I can't find any literature on it.

Comment: My guess is if you display, e.g. the text `TV` and you have explicitly specified that the `T` should be displayed in your font, but the `V` should not, it simply displays the T and the V in different fonts and won't try to make a ligature out of them. What else can it do?